# Are there immigration officers who speak Bahasa Indonesia in Kaohsiung, Taiwan airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, taiwan, language-barrier

Does anyone have experience with this? From what I found on the internet so far, and from my experience in Taoyuan airport, it seems like you need to speak Chinese or English to make it through immigration without much language barrier issues.

And if there will likely be language barriers for someone who speaks Bahasa Indonesia, is there an easy way to find someone who can translate?

Comment: Not sure you will, but for sure there will be many chinese-indonesians onboard who are willing to translate.

Comment: I'm not sure about Kaohsiung, but in Taipei the statement "you need to speak Chinese or English to make it through immigration without much language barrier issues" would be wrong, according to my experience. Nobody has ever asked me anything when I was going through immigration.

Answer (score 3):

I have entered Koahsiung airport ten times. Twice I have seen officers asking questions of everyone. They used a board with pictures on it. Once was asking about meat products, the other time about have you been in China.
No verbal language was needed, and the officers were cheerful.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure if there will be, this will be hard to tell especially at different times and shifts.

In advance as long as you just provide them with any documents they can ask for (passport and any other documents) then you can just make it clear you don’t speak their language. If you present all the documents they may ask for you should be able to proceed with no issues.

If further questioning needs to be done then they will always have an available translator/interpreter even though you might have to wait.

There are several services that could reduce the language barrier:

## E-gates

In this case if you are eligible applying for the e-gate service might be useful. You have a lower chance of having a big language barrier there. You must be a **ROC citizen or holding residency in Taiwan with multiple entry permits** to be eligible for this service.

## Online arrival card

[This website](https://www.roc-taiwan.org/at_de/post/596.html) states that the following people must fill out an arrival card, if you’re not a citizen/resident of ROC (Taiwan). This can be filled out online [here](https://oa1.immigration.gov.tw/nia_acard/acardAddAction.action) to reduce the language barrier.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that you will even have to say any word at all.

You could try asking the people next to you in the plane if they can help you with immigrations, they can have their passports checked at the same time as you, like families do.

If they would have any questions they will contact a translator for you if they don't have anyone working who can speak your language.

All this however applies to all airports everywhere.